# Tabulator animation of group rows

Tags: tabulator

I have been trying for some time to add animation to a change in visibility of the rows belonging to a group. In other words, when you click the arrow for a group and the rows become visible for that group. I know there is the actual row itself and the data in the row that both need to be animated.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible im afraid. The rows are added and removed from the table as the group is expanded/collapsed, because they aren't hidden but removed there is nothing to animate on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!